# Where is the performance of reentrantlock?

Tags: java

Why reentrantlock is better than performance, I see eventually will call the park method to block. Is it just a matter of several cas operations before the park is better than synchronization? Before jdk does not optimize the synchronization

Comment: It sounds like you're just putting together some ideas that you have read here and there but I have no idea what you're asking. Note that ReentrantLock does not in any way claim to have a better performance than synchronized, that's not why it exists (read the javadoc). For many cases, synchronized has better performance. But it depends on your JVM version as well.

Comment: I read a book saying that reentrantlock in jdk1.5 is better than synchronization. But I do not know where the source code is good, my understanding is that the thread blocking needs to be converted from the user state to the system state by the operating system to block the current thread, which will be a great loss of time, but I see the reentrantock source also park blocking, which I You can't understand this better than synchronization.

Comment: Are you using jdk1.5? Do you know it's been unsupported for a long time? You should move to a more modern VM - JDK9 or JDK10.

Comment: 'Where is the performance?' and 'better than performance' are both meaningless. Please rephrase your question so it means something.

Comment: I know that I'm also using jdk8, but I want to know why jdk1.5 Reentrantlock is better than synchronize

Answer (score 0):

`ReentrantLock` and `synchronized` both have same performance.
These two cannot be differentiated by saying performance as a parameter.
But using `Reentrant lock` is better when compared to `synchronized` keyword because `ReentrantLock` has more inbuilt functions.
It is a class which uses some synchronization techniques which provides a layer of abstraction by many inbuilt methodss

Comment: This is incorrect, they have different performances. Synchronized is heavily optimized in the JVM while ReentrantLock is not, so synchronized is often faster on modern JVMs, but it’s depending on many characteristics of the usage such as how heavily the lock is contended.